# Generating Xtext projects programmatically on Xtext version 2.17.0 produces error

Tags: xtext, java-11

I'm generating Xtext projects programmatically using the Xtext version 2.17.0 (Java 11). The whole process is:

1. In my own maven project I'm generating those Xtext projects programmatically.
2. When projects are generated I write grammar to the runtime project and run mvn compile on the parent Xtext project, in order to generate grammar artifacts (like by running Wme2 workflow in Eclipse IDE).
3. I add org.eclipse.ui.console;bundle-version="3.8.100" to the manifest of the ui project. Then also one jar to the Bundle-ClassPath, so the final Manifest looks like this:

```
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: org.mealy.ui
Bundle-Vendor: My Company
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.mealy.ui; singleton:=true
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Require-Bundle: org.mealy,org.mealy.ide,org.eclipse.xtext.ui,org.eclipse
 .xtext.ui.shared,org.eclipse.xtext.ui.codetemplates.ui,org.eclipse.ui.e
 ditors;bundle-version="3.5.0",org.eclipse.ui.ide;bundle-version="3.5.0"
 ,org.eclipse.ui,org.eclipse.compare,org.eclipse.xtext.builder,org.eclip
 se.xtext.xbase.lib;bundle-version="2.14.0",org.eclipse.xtend.lib;bundle
 -version="2.14.0";resolution:=optional,org.eclipse.ui.console;bundle-ve
 rsion="3.8.100"
Import-Package: org.apache.log4j
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-11
Automatic-Module-Name: org.mealy.ui
Export-Package: org.mealy.ui.internal,org.mealy.ui.quickfix,org.mealy.ui
 .contentassist
Bundle-Activator: org.mealy.ui.internal.MealyActivator
Bundle-ClassPath: lib/mealyMachine-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,
 .
```

4. After that I'm generating some source code files etc.
5. Then I'm manually running mvn package on the parent Xtext project in order to build all the projects and get jars representing Eclipse plugin and language server.

But when running the last point on the 2.17.0 version of the Xtext (with Java 11) something is added to the MANIFEST.MF of the ui Xtext project and mvn package fails with following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-plugin:1.3.0:p2-metadata-default (default-p2-metadata-default) on project org.mealy.ui: Execution default-p2-metadata-default of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-plugin:1.3.0:p2-metadata-default failed. IllegalArgumentException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-plugin:1.3.0:p2-metadata-default (default-p2-metadata-default) on project org.mealy.ui: Execution default-p2-metadata-default of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-plugin:1.3.0:p2-metadata-default failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-p2-metadata-default of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-plugin:1.3.0:p2-metadata-default failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.publisher.P2GeneratorImpl.getCanonicalArtifact(P2GeneratorImpl.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.publisher.P2GeneratorImpl.generateMetadata(P2GeneratorImpl.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.plugins.p2.P2MetadataMojo.attachP2Metadata(P2MetadataMojo.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.plugins.p2.P2MetadataMojo.execute(P2MetadataMojo.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.plugins.p2.P2MetadataDefaultMojo.execute(P2MetadataDefaultMojo.java:33)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    ... 22 more
```

The Manifest.mf of the UI Xtext project looks at the end like this:

```
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: org.mealy.ui
Bundle-Vendor: My Company
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.mealy.ui; singleton:=true
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Require-Bundle: org.mealy,org.mealy.ide,org.eclipse.xtext.ui,org.eclipse
 .xtext.ui.shared,org.eclipse.xtext.ui.codetemplates.ui,org.eclipse.ui.e
 ditors;bundle-version="3.5.0",org.eclipse.ui.ide;bundle-version="3.5.0"
 ,org.eclipse.ui,org.eclipse.compare,org.eclipse.xtext.builder,org.eclip
 se.xtext.xbase.lib;bundle-version="2.14.0",org.eclipse.xtend.lib;bundle-version="2.14.0";bundle
 -version="2.14.0";resolution:=optional,org.eclipse.ui.console;bundle-ve
 rsion="3.8.100",
 org.eclipse.ui.editors,
 org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib;bundle-version="2.14.0",
 org.eclipse.xtext.ui.shared
Import-Package: org.apache.log4j
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-11
Automatic-Module-Name: org.mealy.ui
Export-Package: org.mealy.ui.internal,org.mealy.ui.quickfix,org.mealy.ui
 .contentassist,
 org.mealy.ui.contentassist
Bundle-Activator: org.mealy.ui.internal.MealyActivator
Bundle-ClassPath: lib/mealyMachine-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,
 .
```

Running the same code with Xtext 2.16.0 and Java 8 doesnt produce such error and doesnt write anything to the manifest when running point 5 from my list.

What could be the problem ?

Comment: what about changing only one variable at a time to see if this is related to Xtext 2.17 or Java 11. Also: did you try tycho 1.4

Comment: besides that: did you check if pom and manifest fit together?

Comment: => can you please provide a sample project on github showing the problem

Comment: Also knowing what the something is. The generator writes the manifest so there might be a bug in that code but again we need details

Comment: EG the newlines in the manifest look bogus

Comment: https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-extras/issues/406

Comment: => Test With 2.18.0-SNAPSHOT. Or avoid the merger taking action

Comment: How can I avoid merger taking action ? I tested it on 2.18.0-SNAPSHOT and there is the same behavior. But just in case when bundle-version is at the end of the line and broken in the middle of the string like: 
`bundle
 -version="2.14.0"; 
`
There are no newLine characters in the first manifest because I didnt put them there when I was adding the new stuff there. But after adding them behind all the commas bundle-version is no more broken in the middle, so no error occurs. But the thing is that some lines are added to the manifest anyway, so something is there twice..how can I avoid that ?

Comment: please provide a complete example (the project before you start the workflow)

Comment: i also dont understand why you dont have likebreaks?

Comment: Sorry I cant publish the whole code. 
I don't have linebreaks because when I'm reading the manifest like this:
`            String current = manifest.getMainAttributes().getValue("Require-Bundle");
` the value of require-bundle is the string with all the values but without the linebreaks. Then I add org.eclipse.ui.console like this: 
` manifest.getMainAttributes().putValue("Require-Bundle",current + ",org.eclipse.ui.console;bundle-version=\"3.8.100\"");` ... that's why there are no linebreaks

Comment: simply create a hello world greeting project. change the manifest so that it reproduces the problem. open a bug at github.com/eclipse/xtext-core

Comment: https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-core/issues/1120 issue created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you do stumbled over a bug. as a workaround you can try to disable manifest merging

```
            eclipsePlugin = {
                enabled = true
                manifest = {
                    merge = false
                }
            }
```

Comment: this helped. thanks a lot Christian Dietrich ! is there any way how to add this fragment to the wme2 workflow programmatically ? Is it possible to get java object out of the wme2 workflow based on .wme2 file and then change this configuration ?

Comment: i am not aware of an option in the wizard for that. maybe you can file an enhancement request for  that.